# How to set original image height & width on resize script?

Tags: php

I've finally been able to complete the script for an multiple image resizer, currently it's resizing the original image into 3 other sizes, but I am unable to figure out how to set the original height and width. I have used the `getimagesize()` but it does not seem to work.

The whole code is here but I don't think it's necessary to post all of it here. *http://pastebin.com/UR75tdj3*

I have done the following to set each of the images height and width I'd like them to resize into.

```
$uploadedfile       = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

list($width,$height)= getimagesize($uploadedfile);

#large
$largeWidth     = 670;
$largeHeight        = 330;
$largeTmp           = imagecreatetruecolor($largeWidth, $largeHeight);

#medium
$mediumwidth        = 330;
$mediumheight       = 330;
$mediumTmp          = imagecreatetruecolor($mediumWidth,$mediumHeight);

#small
$smallWidth     = 327;
$smallHeight        = 158;
$smallTmp           = imagecreatetruecolor($smallWidth,$smallHeight);
```

but I wanted to enter the orignal into another folder as well, so I did the following thinking that `getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])` would return them correctly but it did not.

```
#original
$originalWidth      = $width;    //here and
$originalHeight = $height;   // here 
$originalTmp        = imagecreatetruecolor($originalWidth,$originalHeight);
```

So how do I get the original image height and width as I have tried to do above?

$originalWidth and $originalHeight should return the specific images width & height, but it does not, that is the only issue I am having.

Comment: Why don't you simply copy the original instead of processing it? Copying takes a lot less resources from image processing.

Answer (score 1):

you want to check the size of 
`$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`

the actull uploaded file as stored on the system

not `$_FILES['file']['name']` which is just the filename

Comment: I should have posted that specific part above, the code is actually checking $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];. I edited the code above, it was my mistake.

Comment: They should not be defined as they're suppose to equal the originals tmp image height and width but it does not. I used getimagesize to retrive but when I use $height or $width to set them it does not work.